# How to Fix the Java Virtual Machine error when running java from command line

Tags: java, virtual-machine

I have already compiled my code into three CLASS files and used this on the command line:

```
java -cp . CreateObjectDemo
```

To create the Java Virtual machine and run it.  The error I got was:

> Unrecognized option:-
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred.  Program will exit.

This has happened before.  How do I fix it and what is the problem? I am running this on the command line using the JDK 8.

Comment: This link maybe helpful for you: http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html

Comment: don't put a space between `-` and `cp`

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you copied the command line from an outlook email or any other source which used an editor with autocorrect/formatting.

The `-` in front of 'cp' should be a minus sign, but is, in fact, an mdash or any other glyph which looks similar (or even identical depending on font), but isn't the same for a computer.